# Probability of a model given an image

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio, image-processing

I would like to write the likelihood function for an image with respect to theoretically predicted values. Assuming uniform Gaussian noise, the pixels are statistically independent, and we can write a likelihood that is simply the product of independent normal distributions:

$
p(D|M)=\prod\limits_{x,y}\mathcal{N}(d_{x,y}|m_{x,y},\sigma)
$

Where $D$ is the image and $M$ is the theoretical model. However, this likelihood seems incorrect, when you consider that a two pure noise images, with the same variance, would have a nontrivial probability against each other:

$
p(D_1|D_2)=\prod\limits_{x,y}\mathcal{N}(D_{1_{x,y}}|D_{2_{x,y}},\sigma)
$

My question is, how can we adjust the likelihood so that it truly tells you **the probability that model-data match is better than random**? One thought is that the likelihood seems to comprise a multiple hypothesis testing situation, so maybe it needs correction. But I'm not totally sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(D|\bar{M})$ be the probability of the image under the 'random' assumption.  Then the posterior probability of the model vs. random is:
$$
p(M|D) = \frac{p(D|M)p(M)}{p(D|M)p(M) + p(D|\bar{M})p(\bar{M})}
$$
This can be written as a transformation of a likelihood ratio:
$$
p(M|D) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{p(D|\bar{M}) p(\bar{M})}{p(D|M)p(M)}}
$$
Note you will have to supply a prior probability $p(M)$ for the model vs. random. See the Wikipedia entry on [Bayes factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor).

Comment: Cool solution. I haven't seen this before, using a likelihood ratio to define a probability distribution - do you happen to know any references on that? My only concern is, $p(D|\bar M)$ is hard to define. One idea is to think of it as an average value $P_{noise}=<\prod \limits^{Npix} \mathcal{N}(\Delta I|\sigma)>$. Assuming the noise is centered around 0, this is just equal to the product of all the normalizing values, $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}})^{Npix}$. I'm not sure if this fits in with the scheme you suggested.